# Is there a way to trigger settimeout function according to the video time that's currently being played?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a video that is currently running in my page and i want to call settimeout function at certain video time.

For example i want to call the settimeout function at 10th second of the video time and here the user can pause the video at his will.basically i want to sync settimeout function's time with video time.

```
<video id="video" autoplay controls>
<source id="mp4" src="https://api.imaginedreality.in/?filename={{video}}" 
type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script>
    window.onload=start;
    function start(){
        setTimeout(showdiv,10000)
     }
    function showdiv(){ 
           document..getElementById('divid').style.display="block"
     }
</script>
```

This is what i was trying but, in here there is no any relation between videotime and setTimeout function and that's exactly i want to establish

Comment: currently am using settimeout(function,10000) hoping that it gets triggered at 10th second but if user paused the video at 5th second and wait for 5 seconds , this timeout function is being called which is messing the things.

Comment: Could you please share with us your attempt so far? What code have you attempted?

Comment: @TheGrandJ Done sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just listen to the `progress`, `play`, and `seeked` events on the video, and when you get it see if you are more than ten seconds in, and if not, set a timeout to check in the appropriate number of seconds?

```js
let timeout;
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('play', checkVideo);
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('seeked', checkVideo);
document.getElementById('video').addEventListener('progress', checkVideo);

function checkVideo(e) {
    if (e.timeStamp > 10000) {
        document.getElementById('divid').style.display="block";
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            if (e.target.currentTime >= 9.9) {
                document.getElementById('divid').style.display="block";
            }
        }, 10000 - (e.target.currentTime * 1000));
    }
}
```

```css
#divid {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="divid">Test</div>
<video id="video" autoplay controls>
<source id="mp4" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4" 
type="video/mp4">
</video>
<script>

</script>
```